# Error with Stripe "PAY" | Error con STRIPE pasarela de pago

Tags: android, stripe, integer

Tengo un error cuando inicio la aplicación, He visto la documentación pero justo de ahí sale eso, Podrian ayudarme?

I have this error when I started app, I look the documentation but it was :( Can help me please?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve este error en my android studio cuando yo apreto el button de pay.
On my android studio can look this error when I pay with the button
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto es sacado de la misma documentación de Stripe, me parece raro que saliera error viniendo de ellos directamente ya que no estoy cambiando nada relevante en realidad, solo lo que se deberia identificar que es la pk que no pongo por seguridad en esta ocasión.
Link de Stripe documentación tal vez con ello puedan ayudarme incluso mas, gracias! https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder
"SERVIDOR CON NODEJS" "CLIENTE CON JAVA(ANDROID)"
El código de java:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.stripe.android.ApiResultCallback;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentIntentResult;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams;
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentIntent;
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethodCreateParams;
import com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
public class CheckoutActivityJava extends AppCompatActivity {
    // 10.0.2.2 is the Android emulator's alias to localhost
    private static final String BACKEND_URL = "http://localhost:3000/";
    private OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    private String paymentIntentClientSecret;
    private Stripe stripe;
    private TextView amountTextView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
        amountTextView = findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
        // Configure the SDK with your Stripe publishable key so it can make requests to Stripe
        stripe = new Stripe(
                getApplicationContext(),
                Objects.requireNonNull("pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx")
        );
        startCheckout();
    }
    private void startCheckout() {
        // Create a PaymentIntent by calling the server's endpoint.
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        double amount = Double.valueOf(amountTextView.getText().toString()) * 100;

        Map<String, Object> payMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        payMap.put("currency", "usd"); //dont change currency in testing phase otherwise it won't work
        itemMap.put("id", "photo_subscription");
        itemMap.put("amount", amount);
        itemList.add(itemMap);
        payMap.put("items", itemList);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(payMap);

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, mediaType);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        httpClient.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new PayCallback(this));
        // Hook up the pay button to the card widget and stripe instance
        Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        payButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);
                stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }
    private void displayAlert(@NonNull String title,
                              @Nullable String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Handle the result of stripe.confirmPayment
        stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new PaymentResultCallback(this));
    }
    private void onPaymentSuccess(@NonNull final Response response) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> responseMap = gson.fromJson(
                Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),
                type
        );
        paymentIntentClientSecret = responseMap.get("clientSecret");
    }
    private static final class PayCallback implements Callback {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<CheckoutActivityJava> activityRef;
        PayCallback(@NonNull CheckoutActivityJava activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
            final CheckoutActivityJava activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity, "On failure Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
            );
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull final Response response)
                throws IOException {
            final CheckoutActivityJava activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity, "On response Error: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                );
            } else {
                activity.onPaymentSuccess(response);
            }
        }
    }
    private static final class PaymentResultCallback
            implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<CheckoutActivityJava> activityRef;
        PaymentResultCallback(@NonNull CheckoutActivityJava activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            final CheckoutActivityJava activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                // Payment completed successfully
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment completed",
                        gson.toJson(paymentIntent)
                );
            } else if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                // Payment failed – allow retrying using a different payment method
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment failed",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(paymentIntent.getLastPaymentError()).getMessage()
                );
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            final CheckoutActivityJava activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            // Payment request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method
            activity.displayAlert("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

El código de xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_checkout"
    tools:context=".CheckoutActivityJava">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amountTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20"
        />


    <com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
        android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Pay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/payButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardInputWidget"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardInputWidget"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardInputWidget"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hola, considera traducir la pregunta, agregar el mensaje del LogCat ya que en ocasiones no es visible para todos los usuarios, agrega una explicación de tu código. Veo que llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio , te sugiero revises nuevamente [ask], recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, saludos.

Comment: Saludos señor Jorge, en realidad todo el código es de la página de Stripe, pero justo de la misma página sale el error me parece raro, igualmente dejaré el código.

Comment: colocá el mensaje del LogCat como texto y más completo si es posible

Answer (score 0):

Debes especificar esta dirección como tu backend:

```
private static final String BACKEND_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";
```

`localhost` se refiere a la red interna de tu dispositivo, la cual no podría conectarse al servidor local de Node que estás corriendo. Al especificar `http://10.0.2.2`, el dispositivo hace un "proxy" para la conectar con tu servidor que está corriendo localmente.

También si no puedes conectarte sobre HTTPS, puedes deshabilitar esta configuración agregando la configuración siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

```
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
```